# How to retrieve data from an api more effective?

Tags: reactjs

I've started an app which is a dashboard panel showing currencies, weather datas, location based news etc. I'm currently using axios for retrieving.

However, I wonder how I retrieve a data from an api smarter? To illustrate, I don't want to use setInterval to update datas. Can you give me a few advices to improve myself?

I researched Etag, server sent events, server push method etc. However usually I didn't find any service to use these effective.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what you need to accomplish. Server push is only relevant if the server provides that service. Retrieving data periodically is a common mechanism--what specifically is wrong with it?

Comment: you can try to use https://tanstack.com/query/latest which is great, `useQuery` hook provides also `refetchInterval` option that could help you achieve what you need

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I have a widget which includes news. A user should see this news which should be updated version in the same page without refresh the page. How can I do that?